# /bin/ls output does not match manpage

Tags: command-line, ls

`ls` manpage says:

```
List  information  about  the FILEs (the current directory by
default).  Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort
is specified.
```

and

```
-a, --all    do not ignore entries starting with .
```

and

```
-1     list one file per line.
```

but

```
/bin/ls -a1
```

lists entries alphabetically by the filename with any leading `.` removed, which is not alphabetically.

The `sort` command does the same.

Is there any way to get `ls` to work the normal way (with `.` files first - which isn't alphabetic either)?

Comment: The period isn't in the alphabet, hence it's locale-dependent, per steeldriver's answer.

Comment: You do understand that files and folders that start with `.` are hidden, correct?

Comment: I think that's why the OP uses the `-a` option.

Comment: It's doing exactly what it says in the man page: sorting the files alphabetically.  It sounds like you want them sorted in ASCIIbetical order instead.

Comment: If it were sorted alphabetically all the dot files would be together, somewhere. They're not. They're scattered about according to the character after the dot. The sorting is according to the first alphabetic character which is not a sort on the filename.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The order is determined by the collation sequence of your locale.

Ex. in my default locale (which is `en_CA.UTF-8`)

```
$ ls -A1
a
.b
c
```

whereas in the `C` locale

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C ls -A1
.b
a
c
```

(I used `-A` instead of `-a` to eliminate the `.` and `..` directories).

---

Another way to get the order you want might be to use the `-v` (version sort) option as suggested in [Grouping hidden files and directories with ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416747/grouping-hidden-files-and-directories-with-ls) - although that's not really what it is intended for:

> ```
>   -v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text
> ```

Since `ls` is almost certainly already aliased inside your `.bashrc` file, you could simply modify the alias(es) there to include the `-v`.

Comment: None of my LC_ variables are set. I'm surprised that the default does something complicated rather something simple. LC_ALL=C now in my startup files.

Comment: @DavidLedger to see your locale settings, type `locale` (they don't appear explicitly as environment variables unless you set them as such)

Comment: Yes, that was set to en_US.UTF-8
  I'm a shell person since '83, so locale generally makes no difference at all.
Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `export LC_ALL=C` to your `.profile`.